# Solving quadratic equation in $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{15})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, congruences

I am studying the theorem that the factorization into irreducibles in $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{15})$ is not unique.

I am stuck in proving that the equations
$a^2\equiv{2,5,13,10} \pmod{15}$ have no solution in $\mathbb{Z}$.

I saw how a linear congruence equation can be solved but I do not know how to solve this equations in order to prove that each of them do not have solution.

Would you help me, please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: $a^2 \equiv 10 \bmod 15$ has solutions: $a=5$ and $a=10$.

Comment: Work$\bmod 3$ and/or $\bmod 5$

Comment: You probably mean $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{15}]$.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use the CRT:

$$\mathbb{Z}_{15} \;\;\;\;\;\;\rightarrow \;\;\;\;\mathbb{Z}_5\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \times \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\mathbb{Z}_3 \\
x^2  \;\;\rightarrow \;\;\;\; (x^2 \bmod 3)\;\;\;\;\times \;\;\;(x^2 \bmod 5) \\
$$
and solve the quadratic modulo equation in each of the smaller field.If you can find a solution in each of the smaller field, then you can find a solution in $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$.